# Subreport with data from stored procedure

Tags: jasper-reports, plpgsql

I am trying to create a jasper report with subreport in which subreport includes a parameter corresponding to a field in main report.subreport query looks like :

`select * from proc_name($P{param1});`

but it is not working with above syntax.
Everything is working fine while using the following syntax, i.e. with static value.

`select * from proc_name(155);`

But I want to create subreport which takes parameter value dynamically from main report. 
How can I do this? 
Valuable suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? Did you define param1 in the subreport? Did you pass the paramater from main report to subreport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution.
:Parameter can be passed in the following format : $P!{param_name}